# Why nginx is not returning OK in status code

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have setup nginx but status code he returns is:

**Status Code: 200**

But on other server with different nginx setup I have:

**Status Code: 200 OK**

Can anyone think of what could be the difference in configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that everything is ok with your configuration.

When nginx serves static files it creates standard "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" response status itself.

But when it passes request to upstream server then it passes through response back without changing it.

Here is an example of script which is executed via proxy_pass directive:

```php
<?php

$msg="OK";
if(isset($_GET["msg"])){
    $msg=$_GET["msg"];
}

header("Status: 200 ".$msg);
echo "hello";
```

In this example we pass parameter into php script and it is used to craft response status:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for msg in "" OK "NOT OK" "Everything is OK"
do
    curl -sI "https://x3m.dev/status/?msg=$msg" |grep -E "HTTP|Server"
done
```

And here is an output of this bash script

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx/1.10.3
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
HTTP/1.1 200 NOT OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
HTTP/1.1 200 Everything is OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
```